# Redirect to a link by <a> tag, as opposed to href attribute?

Tags: jquery, forms, hyperlink

I have a form and a link. Instead of the link being something on the screen to click, I'd like to just go to it. I've tried redirecting to "#" or setting the form action to "#". But it does not seem to work. I need a method of opening or redirecting to a link by `<a>` or by its ID.

```
<form method="post" name="form">
    Name search:
    <input id="ui" type="text" name="ui" />
    <input type="submit" class="Submit" value="submit" />
</form>

$ui = $_POST["ui"];

<a href="#" id="gallery_filter"
          data-filter=".<?php echo $ui; ?>"><?php echo $ui; ?></a>
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Are you saying that you want to redirect to the `href` defined in the `a` element when the form is submit?

Comment: use onclick with window.load in jqyery

Comment: Rory, thanks, yes I'd like to GO to that link. When I click it, it works fine, but when I try appending to the URL #gallery_filter, (after submitting the form) it just reloads whatever is there.

Answer (score -1):

To link to an `a` tag that is being used as an anchor (marking a point on the page), you can use the id preceeded by a `#`:

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="my_page.php#gallery_filter">
  ...
</form>

<a id="gallery_filter">Without an href, this is an anchor not a link.</a>
```

You can't submit a form to a url that is only an anchor (e.g. `action="#gallery_filter"`), but if you add it to the end of the URL then the browser will navigate to it correctly.

Comment: Ok. So, in this case, the page is http://exploreontario.com/test/ I've tried appending the URL with #gallery_filter but it doesn't reload. I can click the link to reload it, of course, but it would be great if I could just append the URL somehow.

Comment: Is there a way I can append the URL with the data-filter attribute? When I load the page with #gallery_filter it reloads the page, but it somehow loses the data-filter info (empty).

Comment: Ok, here's what's happening. After I submit the form, when I click the link, it works. But when I submit the form and then try appending the URL with #gallery_filter it just reloads whatever is already on the page. It's not getting that POST variable somehow.